# TSD3004 error with Visual Studio 2008 Database Project

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio Team System 2008, version 9.0.30729.1 SP. I have a database project that I was working with yesterday with no issues - I was able to build and deploy the database successfully. Today, however, when I open the solution I receive what is listed as a "Warning" that halts any Build/Deploy/etc process, but cannot be suppressed via the Project Properties page.

The Warning reads: "TSD3004: The application encountered an unexpected error. To diagnose this problem, enable tracing. You should contact product support."

I did contact Product Support, but they insist I pay for someone to help me get this fixed. There are zero records returned from an search of "TSD3004" on either MSDN or support.microsoft.com, and there are only three returned from a Google search (all irrelevant).

Can anyone please help me figure out what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried asking on Microsoft's dedicated forum?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/threads/

Actually I guess you did.. :)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/eea24181-e115-4f56-a482-58059160d705

Comment: Jeff,

Thanks for playing, at least... :) BTW, CodingHorror is AWESOME, and is on my Daily Reading List. I also have a printout of the "Then a miracle occurs" cartoon that preceeded Stack Overflow, as it's strikingly similar to a sarcastic data flow diagram I created for corporate management once...

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?  Did you solve your problem Gunny?

Comment: This didn't really solve my problem (which wasn't actually ever solved, I just recreated the project using the database I had deployed the evening before)...think of it more as an "A" for effort. :)